# Fog::Compute::AWS::Error: AuthFailure => AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, chef-infra, knife

chef and aws

I installed knife-ec2 gem in chef. when i try to ping knife ec2 server list getting below error.

I have provided access key and secrete key in knife.rb configuration file.

knife[:aws_access_key_id] = ""
knife[:aws_secret_access_key] = ""

but still getting this error.

ERROR: Fog::Compute::AWS::Error: AuthFailure => AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials.

how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your credentials to the `~/.aws/credentials`

[AWS Credential File](https://github.com/chef/knife-ec2#aws-credential-file)

```
[default]
AWSAccessKeyId=YourAWSAccessKeyID
AWSSecretKey=YourAWSSecretAccessKey
```

The preferred method is to specify them in `Knife.rb`

[Knife.rb Configuration](https://github.com/chef/knife-ec2#kniferb-configuration)

```
knife[:aws_access_key_id] = "Your AWS Access Key ID"
knife[:aws_secret_access_key] = "Your AWS Secret Access Key"
```